# Objective c unable to define macro

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I have this

```
#define sud [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefault]
```

Then I use [sud integerForKey: key]

Compile warning:

```
Class method '+standardUserDefault' not found (return type defaults to 'id')
```

Run time error:

```
+[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefault]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x3c0bc850
```

But I can use another one without any warning:

```
#define man [Manager sharedManager]
```

where 'man' is the game manager (singleton) to store game score etc

Comment: Please close this question. It makes me stupid. thanks

Comment: You can delete from your side

Comment: Sorry, this question has answers and cannot be deleted; flag it for moderator attention instead.

Comment: No, it made you smarter. You now know that using macros is a bad idea in the first place.

Comment: I wonder why they dont allow auto complete on macro

Comment: Typo's happen to the best of us.

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe no way i love macro. just imagine typing [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] all the way

Comment: @dragon112 ... same is true for macros.

Comment: We never make function calls from macro, However in school days we were asked to find max of 3 numbers using macro. **Typo was your un-intentional mistake but small case name for macro was your mistake, that you learnt** :0

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's `standardUserDefaults` (with an s).

Two style notes:

- Cocoa discourages the use of abbreviations.
- You should consider dropping the macros, as they make code less readable and understandable, as demonstrated by your typo bug.